# Make an http request inside error handling Angular 7 RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

Hi catched the error `internal server error` already and logged em. But I dont know how to call the next request inside this error handling. I need to revert the beginning `selectElevation(elevation.id)` request by calling another request method `selectPhase(this.sessionState.phaseId)` if the request `selectElementPricelistConfigurator()` fails.

```
goToConfiguratorAndLoadData(elevation: Elevation) {
        this.apiService.selectElevation(elevation.id).pipe(
            mergeMap( () => this.apiService.selectElementPricelistConfigurator() ),
        ).subscribe(
        (next) => {
            ...
        },
        (err: Error | HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                if (err.status === 500) {
                    console.log('Error', err.status);
                    this.apiService.selectPhase(this.sessionState.phaseId);
                }
            } else {
                throwError(err);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

The server just stops and is not firing this http request.
[image]

Thanks for any help, didnt found any similiar problem.

Edited:

ApiServer - selectPhase Method:

```
selectPhase(phaseId: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.apiUrl + '/phases/select', {
        identifier: phaseId,
    });
}
```

Comment: You should use this: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html, also check this out: https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.apiService.selectPhase(this.sessionState.phaseId)` request is not called because there is no .subscribe() on it (assuming it returns an observable).
Although, this is not the good way to do it, the good way is using the operator **catchError** in order to modify the error and perform some custom actions.

With **catchError**, you don't need to 'subscribe()' to the observable, catcError will flat the observable that you return on it's callback function.

**Example**:

```
goToConfiguratorAndLoadData(elevation: Elevation) {
        this.apiService.selectElevation(elevation.id).pipe(
            mergeMap( () => this.apiService.selectElementPricelistConfigurator() ),
            catchError((err: Error | HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 500) {
                    console.log('Error', err.status);
                    return this.apiService.selectPhase(this.sessionState.phaseId);
                } else {
                   return throwError(err);
                }
            })
        ).subscribe(
        (next) => {
            ...
        }

    );
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Gonna test it Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

```
this.apiService.selectPhase(this.sessionState.phaseId)
```

return a RxJS Observable, you need to subscribe to it for the request to fire.

To quote the [official doc](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable):

> To invoke the Observable and see these values, we need to subscribe to it: